# How to deploy pods across all nodes evenly in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

I have a few Kubernetes clusters with different #of nodes in each. And my deployment of config has "replicas: #nodes". There is no specific config set up for scheduling that pod but after deployment, I see strange behavior in terms of the distribution of pods on nodes.

Example:

*For 30 nodes cluster (30 replicas) all 30 pod replicas distributed across 25 nodes only and other 5 nodes are sitting ideal in the cluster.*
Similar cases for many other different clusters and this count varies in every new/redeployment.

Question:

I want to distribute my pod replicas across all nodes. If I set "replicas: #nodes" then I should have one pod replica in each node. If I increase/double the replicas count then it should distribute evenly.
is there any specific configuration in deployment yaml for Kubernetes?

Configuration with node AntiAffinity, but still this one is behaving as above. Tried with "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution" and that one did deployed one pod in each node, but if I increase the replicas or any node goes down during the deployment then then whole deployment fails.

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test1
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values:
              - test1
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

Comment: What problems do you experience with that pods is not evenly distributed? For what reason is it important to you that pods is scheduled to all nodes? Kubernetes abstract away the infrastructure so you should not think too much of this, unless you have a problem with it.

Comment: What you're looking for is probably something like `podAntiAffinity`
with `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` which weighs the scheduling towards not putting a pod on a node where pods with a certain label already exists. It does not _fail_ scheduling if it's not possible to schedule on a different node, just prefers a bit extra not to.

Comment: @Jonas- I faced the worst distribution of pods, 32 pods distributed across only 3 nodes instead of having 32 nodes cluster.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson- Already tried with above configuration you suggested but it, still behaving as I gave example in question. In my config where I want to prefer node not having similar pod label. But still it's distributed across 28 nodes instead of 32. I don't have any other pod running on those nodes which can cause the problem of resource usages.

Comment: If 32 of the pods fits on only 3 nodes, why do you have soo many nodes... it sounds like the pods use very little resouces. So the scheduling is perfectly fine. I don't see how this is a problem?

Comment: Can you paste the logs from kube-scheduler? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885793/kubernetes-kube-scheduler-is-not-correctly-scoring-nodes-for-pod-assignment

Comment: The anti-affinity should work, you are having a different issue. Can you post more details such as the full deployment YAML and provide the output of a describe node, one for a node with pods on it and one for a node without pods on it.

Comment: One thing to note, is that your number of pods and nodes should be equally divisible over the number of AZs you have - we've seen issues in AWS where we have 4 nodes, and 16 replicas .. and the developers _expect_ these to be evenly distributed, but the `failure-domain` label uses the AZ, and this means that they won't be evenly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a 1 pod per node deployment, you should be using a [daemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) instead of a replicaSet. Alternately, if you need more than 1 pod per node and still want the pod distribution to be mostly even, you can use pod anti-affinity as I discussed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057561/kubernetes-evenly-distribute-the-replicas-across-the-cluster/57060271#57060271)

Comment: Please see updated question details. I have configuration for pod anti-affinity but still it's not helping me for even distribution.

Comment: Unfortunately, preferred does not guarantee anything. The scheduler will try to spread the pods out as much as possible but it still won't be a perfect distribution. The weight you've put is a big part of the decision making, but there are many other factors as well

Answer (score 0):

see Pod Topology Spread Constraints https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/
this feature gives you permission to finely define how your pods will be distributed across your cluster based on regions, zones, nodes, and other user-defined topology domains.

So you may define your own rules how to distribute pods.

Comment: which version of k8s does support this?

Comment: 1.19 (for earlier versions need to enable some additional feature gates. see link in answer)